# How do I get values from a nested array pushed into a flat array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, ramda.js

I have an api returning a dataset like this:

```json
const data = {
  session: ....,
  timestamp: ....,
  samples: [
    {
      key: 'I',
      values: [
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
        // ....
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'I',
      values: [
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -100.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.3334 },
        // ....
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'I',
      values: [
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
        // ....
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

what I want to do is grab `values` from `samples` and push them into a new array that will just be a flat array, something like this:

```js
const newData = [
  [
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
    // ....
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -100.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.3334 },
    // ....
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
    // ....
  ]
```

I was able to get `samples` into a new array like so:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  newArray: [...prevState.newArray, [...data.samples] ]
}));
```

I'm open to using libraries like `lodash` or `ramda` if there's a library that exists that would make this easier.

Comment: `data.samples.flatMap(x => x.values);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` or `flatMap()`:

```
const newData = data.reduce((accumulated, current) => [...accumulated, ...current.values], []);
```

Or:

```
const newData = data.flatMap(item => item.values);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `.reduce()`:

```
let ans = data.samples.reduce((cum,x)=>{
 return [...cum,...(x.values)];   
},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ramda you can use `R.chain` with `R.prop` to values flatten all the `values`:

```js
const fn = R.chain(R.prop('values'))

const data = {"samples":[{"key":"I","values":[{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-37.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-32.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":1.1234}]},{"key":"I","values":[{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-100.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":5.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":5.3334}]},{"key":"I","values":[{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-37.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-32.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":1.1234}]}]}

const result = fn(data.samples)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

With lodash you can use `_.flatMap()`:

```js
const data = {"samples":[{"key":"I","values":[{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-37.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-32.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":1.1234}]},{"key":"I","values":[{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-100.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":5.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":5.3334}]},{"key":"I","values":[{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-37.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":-32.1234},{"timing":"12356timingdatething","reading":1.1234}]}]}

const result = _.flatMap(data.samples, 'values')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```